# Can't connect to Samba network

Tags: 14.04, samba

I have set up Samba network on my PC and I can connect to it from my phone but when I try via laptop running 14.04 it just keeps asking for creditentals over and over again and I am not sure where problem is,host PC is Windows 8.1 and username has @ in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you configured samba with command prompt (Terminal), you've need to set guest ok = yes

Example:

```
[Shared Folder]
  comment = My Folder
  path = /files/my folder
  browseable = yes
  read only = no
  guest ok = yes
```

Test out "guest ok = yes"!